# ¿por qué me da error al insertar la ruta de php?

Tags: php, vscode

Estoy armando el ambiente de desarrollo para programar con php para mi sitio web, pero tengo muchas dificultades para instalar php, he tratado muchas formas pero no da error. [image: Configuración de visual studio code]

Comment: Has intentado usar solo `/`?

Comment: Tienes que escapar el caracter usando \\ o /

Comment: El según la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), el caracter '\'  se utiliza para escapar caracteres que tienen un significado especial: *The backslash (\) character is used to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.*

Comment: gracias colegas, estaban en lo correcto , tenía que usar \\ o /